# Video Lenght by JavaScript before uploading video file

Tags: javascript, html, video, file-upload

I like to find out the video lenght from a local file on users desktop before uploading. The "video.onload" event didn't fire (see code) so I helped myself with a setTimeout once the video is loaded. But I don't like to use the setTimeout. Is there a cleaner way?

```js
function handleFileSelect(evt) {
 var files = evt.target.files; // FileList object
    var output = [];
    for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {
  var video = document.getElementById('myVideo');
  var obj_url = window.URL.createObjectURL(f);
  video.src = obj_url;
        console.log(f.name+ " " +f.type);
        console.log(video.src);

  video.onload = function() {
    // It didn't work so I used delayedchk() 
    // window.URL.revokeObjectURL(this.src);
  }
    delayedchk();    
 }
}
document.getElementById('files').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);

function show(){
 vid = document.getElementById("myVideo");
 document.getElementById("laenge").innerHTML = Math.floor(vid.duration);
 vid.play();
  window.URL.revokeObjectURL(vid.src);
}

function delayedchk(){
   var vdur = document.getElementById("myVideo").duration;
    console.log(typeof vdur +' = '+vdur);
    if( isNaN(vdur) ){
       setTimeout(delayedchk,500);
    }else{
  show();
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<body onload="show()">
<video id="myVideo" src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4"></video>
  <h1>Lenght: <span id="laenge"></span> sec.</h1>
  <input type="file" id="files" name="files[]" multiple />
</body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can retrieve the video's [`duration` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/duration) by listening to the [`loadedmetadata`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/loadedmetadata_event) event:

```js
var myVideoPlayer = document.getElementById('myVideo');
myVideoPlayer.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', function() {
  document.getElementById('laenge').innerHTML = myVideoPlayer.duration;
});
```

```html
<h1>Length: <span id="laenge"></span> sec.</h1>
<video id="myVideo" src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4" autoplay></video>
```